# NullPointerException en el método onClick

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Buenas tardes, tengo un pequeño problema con un metodo onClick en un Fragmento

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCardContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/materialdesing"
                android:background="@drawable/materialdesing"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Tittle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nombre"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:textSize="24dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Sub_tittle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ciudad"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Open_Action"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Shared"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/Button_Shared"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Explorar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/Button_Shared"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewExpand"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_circle_preseed"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/details"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:padding="8dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/descripcion"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>
```

Fragmento

```
public class TabAttractionGeneral extends Fragment {

List<GetBeach> GetDataAdapter2;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

TextView time;

String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://mextoursvm.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:81/api/App/GetBeaches";

String JSON_BEACHID = "BEACHID";
String JSON_NAME = "NAME";
String JSON_DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
String JSON_PLACE = "PLACE";
String JSON_LAT = "LAT";
String JSON_LNG = "LNG";



JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;

RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ViewGroup linearLayoutDetails;
private ImageView imageViewExpand;
private ImageView open;
private LinearLayout LinearOpen;

private static final int DURATION = 250;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle save){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabgeneralbusines, container, false);



    // Bloqear la orientación de pantalla LandScape
    Activity a = getActivity();
    if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



    GetDataAdapter2 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerGeneralBusines);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);


    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();

    linearLayoutDetails = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutCardContent);
    imageViewExpand = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);
    LinearOpen = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Open_Action);
    open = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewExpand);
    open.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggleDetails(view);
        }
    });








    return rootView;
}



public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        GetBeach GetDataAdapter = new GetBeach();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataAdapter.setBEACHID(json.getString(JSON_BEACHID));
            GetDataAdapter.setNAME(json.getString(JSON_NAME));
            GetDataAdapter.setDESCRIPTION(json.getString(JSON_DESCRIPTION));
            GetDataAdapter.setPLACE(json.getString(JSON_PLACE));
            GetDataAdapter.setLAT(json.getString(JSON_LAT));
            GetDataAdapter.setLNG(json.getString(JSON_LNG));


        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter2.add(GetDataAdapter);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterBeach(GetDataAdapter2, getActivity());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
}

public void toggleDetails(View view) {
    if (linearLayoutDetails.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        ExpandAndCollapseViewUtil.expand(linearLayoutDetails, DURATION);
        imageViewExpand.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp);
        rotate(-180.0f);
    } else {
        ExpandAndCollapseViewUtil.collapse(linearLayoutDetails, DURATION);
        imageViewExpand.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp);
        rotate(180.0f);
    }
}

private void rotate(float angle) {
    Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, angle, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setDuration(DURATION);
    imageViewExpand.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

}

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: ixtapa.com.mx.ixtapazihua, PID: 4295
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ixtapa.com.mx.ixtapazihua/ixtapa.com.mx.ixtapazihua.ContentIxtapaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at ixtapa.com.mx.ixtapazihua.Fragments.TabAttractionGeneral.onCreateView(TabAttractionGeneral.java:101)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5452)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: ¿Qué activity quieres usar aquí: `Activity a = getActivity();`?

Comment: César ¿puedes clickear en esta parte      ` at ixtapa.com.mx.ixtapazihua.Fragments.TabAttractionGeneral.onCreateView(TabAttractionGeneral.java:101)` y señalar que parte de tu código te manda el cursor?

Comment: @A.Cedano ahí solo es para que la pantalla no realice un landscape, saludos

Comment: @x4mp73r me lleva directamente a la parte del método. `open.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleDetails(view);
            }
        });
`

Comment: Es como si tu intentases usar tu fragmento antes de que el mismo esté listo para usar... ¿Qué hay en esta línea: `at ixtapa.com.mx.ixtapazihua.Fragments.TabAttractionGeneral.onCreateView(TabAttractionGeneral.java:101)`, en la línea 101.?

Comment: `open.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleDetails(view);
            }
        });` Mando un Intent de una activida hacia el fragmento

Comment: Tu buscas todos tus vistas en `rootView`. Asumiendo que el layout que compartiste es `layout/tabgeneralbusines.xml`, no encuentro todos los _id_ que luego buscas dentro de esta vista en tu layout. Puedes aclarar que layout es que compartiste (nombre exacto) y si es el layout completo? Las unicas vistas en que te puede salir una NPE en esta parte son `open` y `recyclerView`.  Revisa que vista se usa en línea 101 de `TabAttractionGeneral`.

Comment: @CésarManuelRíosGómez Agrega esto a las propiedades de tu _ImageView_  `android:onClick="toggleDetails"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la forma en que manejas los eventos lo correcto es, por ejemplo:

En las propiedades de tu *Imageview*

```
<ImageView  
 ...... 
 android:clickable="true"  
 android:onClick="metodoBonito"  
 .....
 />  

Método el que quieres que maneje:

 public void metodoBonito(View view) {  
  //bla bla bla.....
 }
```

Por lo tanto, se te ha pasado colocar `onClick` a tu `imageview`, el cual le pones el nombre de tu método *toggleDetails*, entonces quedaría así tu `imageView`:

```
               <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewExpand"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_circle_preseed"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/details"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="toggleDetails"
                        android:padding="8dp"/>
```

O bien, en lugar de usar `ImageView` puedes usar `ImageButton`(El cual yo prefiero) y funciona exactamente como un botón y puedes agregarle el escuhador de eventos de la otra forma, ahí no es necesario colocarle la propiedad `onClick` ni nada de eso, ejemplo:

```
  ImageButton imagen = (ImageButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
    imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mostrarMensaje();
        }
    });
```

Claro, tiene bordes que le da aspecto de botón pero puedes quitárselo de manera sencilla agregando un color de fondo transparente   `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tuImagen"
        ....
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        ..../>
```